# Reactstrap DropdownMenu bottom overflow issue

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I have searched the `reactstrap` docs but unfortunately it only provides `DropdownMenu:right` property. What I wanted to achieve is to somehow auto align the drop menu on the bottom such that it won't overflow.

[image]

```
import { 
    UncontrolledButtonDropdown,
    DropdownToggle, 
    DropdownMenu, 
    DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";

<UncontrolledButtonDropdown direction="left">
    <DropdownToggle color="secondary" size="sm">
        <i className="pe-7s-more btn-icon-wrapper"></i>
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem onClick={some_action}>{some_label}</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</UncontrolledButtonDropdown>
```

Is there any way i can get around this issue?

Comment: are you able to show a prototype of the issue?

Comment: updated post with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of your `overflow: hidden/scroll/auto` container. This is standard CSS behavior in that it will hide the content that no longer fits the container's defined dimensions. Reactstrap handles this scenario with the `positionFixed` prop. This will simply position the popover item as a `fixed` element so that it is no longer relative to the `overflow: hidden/scroll/auto` container *unless* the container has `transform` properties.

```
<DropdownMenu positionFixed={true}>
    ...
</DropdownMenu>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-hermann-157ez?file=/src/App.js

Comment: console.log(`salamat pre`)

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer doesn't work for me.

There is another solution from [documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-dropdown--uncontrolled#container):

```
<DropdownMenu container={'body'}>
    ...
</DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: changes the behavior a bit but it works like a charm.